# Spring Data Cassandra - create a table with options values

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

Is there any way to create a table with non-default options values? So far, the `@Table` annotation was enough for my needs, but I need to set up a TTL value different than default. I use version 1.5.15.
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no option support derived from annotations. You can create tables by using [`CreateTableSpecification`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/keyspace/CreateTableSpecification.html).

```
CreateTableSpecification.createTable("mytable").with(TableOption.COMMENT, "my comment");
```

Spring Data for Apache Cassandra isn't really a CQL object generation framework. The schema support is limited to basic usage to "just spin up the objects" without the need to always have a pre-provisioned keyspace.